# Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1 Oracle

Tags: oracle

When running this small script I am receiving error "Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1" not sure where do I making mistake/s?

```
{
DECLARE
  LV_CODE_TXT VARCHAR (5) := 'A';
  LV_ORDERTOTAL_NUM NUMBER(6,2) := 100;
  LV_DISCOUNT_NUM NUMBER(5,2);
BEGIN
  IF LV_CODE_TXT IN ('A','E')
  THEN
    LV_DISCOUNT_NUM =: LV_ORDERTOTAL_NUM * .05;
    DBMS_OUPTUT.PUT_LINE (LV_DISCOUNT_NUM);
  ELSIF LV_CODE_TXT IN ('B','C')
  THEN
    LV_DISCOUNT_NUM := LV_ORDERTOTAL_NUM * .10;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (LV_DISCOUNT_NUM)
  ELSIF LV_CODE_TXT = 'D'
  THEN
    LV_DISCOUNT_NUM := LV_ORDERTOTAL_NUM * .15;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (LV_DISOCUNT_NUM);
  ELSE 
    LV_DISOUNT_NUM := 0;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(LV_DISOUNT_NUM);
  END IF;
END;
}
```

Comment: here "DBMS_OUPTUT"  .PUT_LINE (LV_DISCOUNT_NUM);

Comment: still not sure what I need to change? Do I need to place DBMS_OUTPUT in double quotation marks? I have changed misspelling of local variable but still not working.

Comment: you are missing ; on line DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (LV_DISCOUNT_NUM) after LV_DISCOUNT_NUM := LV_ORDERTOTAL_NUM * .10;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of spelling mistakes, syntax errors and most importantly you do not need opening and closing curly brackets(`{}`) so try the below

```
DECLARE
   LV_CODE_TXT         VARCHAR (5) := 'A';
   LV_ORDERTOTAL_NUM   NUMBER (6, 2) := 100;
   LV_DISCOUNT_NUM     NUMBER (5, 2);
BEGIN
   IF LV_CODE_TXT IN ('A', 'E')
   THEN
      LV_DISCOUNT_NUM := LV_ORDERTOTAL_NUM * .05;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(LV_DISCOUNT_NUM);
   ELSIF LV_CODE_TXT IN ('B', 'C')
   THEN
      LV_DISCOUNT_NUM := LV_ORDERTOTAL_NUM * .10;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (LV_DISCOUNT_NUM);
   ELSIF LV_CODE_TXT = 'D'
   THEN
      LV_DISCOUNT_NUM := LV_ORDERTOTAL_NUM * .15;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (LV_DISCOUNT_NUM);
   ELSE
      LV_DISCOUNT_NUM := 0;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (LV_DISCOUNT_NUM);
   END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, {} brackets I have placed when adding the code.